# Should my query return null when it doesn't find any items?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have a `multiselectlist` where a user can pick some or none `inputvoltages`. When the user selects no `InputVoltages` my query throws a `null exception` when I call `.Tolist()`. Why am I not just getting back an empty list?

I'm using MVC5 C# and entity framework 6.

repository

```
public IQueryable<InputVoltage> All
{
    get { return context.InputVoltages; }
}
```

controller

```
var newInputVoltages = unitOfWorkPds.InputVoltageRepository
    .All.Where(m => engineeringPdsEditViewModel.SelectedInputVoltages
        .Contains(m.Id))
    .ToList<InputVoltage>();
```

`All` does return a list but `SelectedInputVoltages` is null when nothing is selected. I was wondering if that was the issue.

When I use this query and add a where statement for my index page I don't receive a null error when I call `ToList`

```
IQueryable<EngineeringPdsIndexViewModel> query = 
    (from a in context.EngineeringPds
     select new EngineeringPdsIndexViewModel
     {
         Id = a.Id,
         Name = a.Name,
         Status = a.Status,
         AnnualQuantities = a.AnnualQuantities,
         ToMarketDate = a.ToMarketDate,
         SubmittedBy = a.SubmittedBy,
         TargetPrice = a.TargetPrice
     });
```

So I believe Brian has the right idea of what is wrong but here is the issue extended
I have a multiselect box that is populated in the get action method by

```
    IList<InputVoltage> inputVoltagesList = unitOfWorkPds.InputVoltageRepository.All.ToList();
```

then

```
pdsEditViewModel.InputVoltageList = inputVoltagesList.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Text = m.Name, Value = m.Id.ToString() });  in my view I hav@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedApprovals, Model.ApprovalList)
```

but when a user makes no selections the selectedInputvoltages comes into my post controller action as null how do I get it to come in as an empty list?

UPDATE

For anyone who runs into the same problem Brians first answer explains the issue. The work around for submitting a ListBox with empty lists can be found here

[How can I return an empty list instead of a null list from a ListBoxFor selection box in Asp.net MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732667/how-can-i-return-an-empty-list-instead-of-a-null-list-from-a-listboxfor-selection)

Comment: It is definitely not the call to `ToList` that throws the exception since `Where` never returns null.

Comment: I would debug this properly. Make sure `All` is returning something.

Comment: Of course you will not receive an error because the Where extension method will always return a collection, it might be empty but is not null. By calling ToList you will just get an Empty List.
`empty != null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where will not return null.  The problem is in the argument:

`engineeringPdsEditViewModel.SelectedInputVoltages.Contains(m.Id)`

A NULL engineeringPdsEditViewModel or SelectedInputVoltages can cause `NullReferenceException` to be thrown.  So you need to do a null check against these objects.

You can see this play out with a similar test sample.  Here we get a nullrefex because `myString` is null.  So when Where executes it tries to do a comparison and blows up:

```
       var test = new TestClass(1);
        var test2 = new TestClass(2);
        var test3 = new TestClass(3);

        List<TestClass> tests = new List<TestClass>();
        tests.Add(test);
        tests.Add(test2);
        tests.Add(test3);

        string myString = null;

        var result = tests.Where(t => myString.Contains(t.Myint.ToString())).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(result.Count);
```

**Update: (To answer your comment)**

You can return an empty list like this:

```
List<InputVoltage> newInputVoltages = new List<InputVoltage>();
if(engineeringPdsEditViewModel != null && engineeringPdsEditViewModel.SelectedInputVoltages != null)
{
     //Where params are not null so its safe to use them
     newInputVoltages = unitOfWorkPds.InputVoltageRepository
    .All.Where(m => engineeringPdsEditViewModel.SelectedInputVoltages
    .Contains(m.Id))
    .ToList<InputVoltage>();
}
//else no need to do anything...just return the empty list created above
return newInputVoltages;
```

Comment: This is what I thinking the issue was but how would I get an empty list back instead of a null list from my multiselectbox?

Comment: I think I may of been unclear, I have a multiselect box that is populated in the get action method by                 IList<InputVoltage> inputVoltagesList = unitOfWorkPds.InputVoltageRepository.All.ToList(); then             pdsEditViewModel.InputVoltageList = inputVoltagesList.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Text = m.Name, Value = m.Id.ToString() });  in my view I have         @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedApprovals, Model.ApprovalList) but when a user makes no selectionsthe selectedInputvoltages comes into my post controller action as null how do I get it to come in as an empty list?

Comment: @Brian I'm going to add this to the question so its easier to read

Comment: @Bob - I'm finding it difficult to follow the flow of the application from the description.  As it stands I would need to review the controller, view, model and related parts like context and local variables defined therein.  That's just really complicated.  Is there any way you can review the problem with this new information and remove everything that we don't need to be aware of?  A simplified short compile-able example.  It seems to me that the related Razor from the View and the two Controller methods in question should suffice.

Comment: @Brian thankyou for your help I actually was able to solve the issue with your confirmation that selectedInputVoltages was the issue and asking my listbox question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732667/how-can-i-return-an-empty-list-instead-of-a-null-list-from-a-listboxfor-selectio

Answer (score 3):

Any Extension method defined in the BCL for `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>` that returns `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>` will not return null. It might return an empty collection, but that is very different to null.

try this:

```
var newInputVoltages = engineeringPdsEditViewModel.SelectedInputVoltages == null ?
    unitOfWorkPds.InputVoltageRepository.All : 
    unitOfWorkPds.InputVoltageRepository.All.Where(m => engineeringPdsEditViewModel.SelectedInputVoltages.Contains(m.Id)).ToList();
```

Comment: Not your fault, but I'm wondering if `All` is really supposed to be the linq function `All()`.

Comment: No, that's just how my repository is set up.Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

you will not get an empty list and it's expected behaviour it returns null.

Comment: so should I make the query then check if not null then call to list or is there a more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: @Bob : you can add a check to see if it null and handle it or  you can handle null reference exception.

Answer (score 0):

just test the input (I used the [Ternary Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) when you create the variable and you won't need any validation later

```
var newInputVoltages = SelectedInputVoltages.Any() 
          ?  unitOfWorkPds.InputVoltageRepository
                .All.Where(m => engineeringPdsEditViewModel.SelectedInputVoltages.Contains(m.Id))
                .ToList<InputVoltage>()
          : new List<InputVoltage>();
```